# How to split url in reactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

The full url is `/login?redirect=shipping`. I want to split it into two parts like this - `/login?redirect` and `shipping`. I need the second part of the url. that is `shipping` How can I do this in reactjs??

Comment: Are you using `react-router-dom` V6?

Comment: yes @GodWin ....

Answer (score 3):

You can use [useSearchParams](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-search-params) from `react-router-dom` v6.

You can also use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search) *(Provided by Browsers)*

In your case it would be as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { useSearchParams, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export const App = () => {
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const { search } = useLocation();

    console.log(searchParams.get("redirect"));

    // if it's more than 1 value for redirect i.e. redirect=shipping&redirect=shipped
    console.log(searchParams.getAll("redirect")); // will return array of value

    // you can use URLSearchParams also by passing search query
    console.log(new URLSearchParams(search).get("redirect"));
    // URLSearchParams is provided by Browser.
    return <div>Search Param</div>;
};
```

**PS:** Follow `useSearchParams` approach if using react and specifically `react-router-dom` **V6** or else go for `URLSearchParams`